# A nice application of a result in probability

Tags: pr.probability

I am looking for a nice application of the following result in order to understand its significance.

Let $A$ be a set of cardinality $n$ and $S \subset A$ be constructed in such a way that the elements of $A$ are included in $S$ independently with probability $p$. Then, the expected value of $\# S$ is $pn$, and one has:

- $\Pr(\# S < \frac12 pn) \le \exp\left( -\frac1{100} pn \right)$
- $\Pr(\# S \ge 2 pn) \le \exp\left( -\frac1{100} pn \right)$

Comment: these are bounds on the [regularized incomplete beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function) --- is there more to say?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker could you please elaborate?

Comment: isn't ${\rm Pr}(\#S < \tfrac{1}{2}pn) =I_{1-p}(n-\tfrac{1}{2}pn,1+\tfrac{1}{2}pn)$ ?

Comment: A rather intuitive approach to such inequalities is via Chernov's bound, see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound , or Talagrand's concentration results, see e.g. https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/03/254a-notes-1-concentration-of-measure/

Answer (score 4):

For an application of the first inequality:  The fraction of all $v$-vertex graphs that have fewer than $\frac14 \binom{v}{2}$ edges is ridiculously tiny (smaller than $e^{-v(v-1)/400}$).